# Why could the function definition in Dart be after the calling of the function?

Tags: dart, function-definition, function-call

Why could the function definition in Dart be after the calling of the function? I think the Dart compiler would read the code top to bottom, left to right? At the moment the compiler sees the calling, how could it know what is `calculateArea`?

```
void main() {
  double result = calculateArea(12, 5, false);
  print ('The result for a rectangle is ' + result.toString());
  result = calculateArea(12, 5, true);
  print ('The result for a triangle is ' + result.toString());
}

double calculateArea(double width, double height, [bool isTriangle = false]) {
  double area;
  if (isTriangle) {
    area = width * height / 2;
  } 
  else {
    area = width * height;
  }
  return area;
}
```

Comment: The Dart compiler are not doing a single scan of your code and then directly turns it into machine instructions. It is operating in multiple phases like most other compilers for modern programming languages.

Comment: Where could I find the websites or sources that mention it? I want to find out more about it. It seems like Dart does not have much documentation for searching and finding what I want.

Comment: What information are you looking for? There are a lot but I think a good start is this: https://mrale.ph/dartvm/

Comment: @julemand101 , is it similar to the function hoisted in JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand the question.

Comment: In JavaScript, function declarations or `var` variables are declared at the bottom of the file that we could invoke or use at the top of the file. What I mean is that.

Comment: This is not related to Dart or the original question. Please ask a new question if you want an answer to this. Comments should only be used for clarification of the original question.